# Will Windows 11 require secure boot is enabled, or just requires secure boot capable UEFI motherboard?

Tags: windows-11, secure-boot

I am planning to fresh install Windows 11 to a ASUS Prime Z590 motherboard with 11th generation intel CPU

My question, will Windows 11 require secure boot is enabled, or just requires secure boot capable UEFI motherboard?

My concert if I enable secure boot, will the UEFI ask for password every boot time?
I also do not know if secure boot is enabled, can I boot from a rescue USB what my backup software (Macrium 8) creates?

(Obviusly I have no idea how and what secure boot does/works)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because finding this information only requires a simple search for "secure boot" on the internet.

Comment: Note that "Secure Boot" *does not ask for passwords.*

Comment: Windows 11 requires Secure Boot to be enabled. You should do research on Secure Boot

Comment: The three duplicates collectively answer the majority of your questions explaining what secure boot is, what you can do regarding other operating systems (old version of Windows but still relevant) and whether Windows 11 actually requires it. It may help to search our previous questions on the matter: https://superuser.com/search?q=secure+boot and https://superuser.com/search?q=secure+boot+windows+11